# output parameter does not have a value

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have simple SQL insert into command which does not work using the ExecuteNonQuery. Here's my command

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[et_personhasdevice] 
            ([id_naturalperson], 
             [id_device], 
             [pd_macaddress], 
             [pd_recordate], 
             [pd_status], 
             [created_at], 
             [created_by]) 
SELECT id_person, 
       1, 
       @macAddress, 
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
       'A', 
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
       'ETC' 
FROM   [dbo].et_person 
WHERE  pe_address = @personAddress

SET @ID_PERSONHASDEVICE = Scope_identity()
```

This is my block of code

```
using (SqlCommand command = helper.GetSqlQueryCommand(query))
{
    //In parameters
    foreach (string key in parameters.Keys)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(key, parameters[key]);

    //out parameters
    foreach(string key in outParameters.Keys)
    {
        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = key;
        parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;         
        parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    }

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.Parameters["ID_PERSONHASDEVICE"].Value //it does not have a value

}
```

The execution does not throw any exception but also does not inserted the record in the database, also I already check the command and works well in the management studio

Comment: And is `ID_PERSONHASDEVICE` in `outParameters`? Why are you calling `ExecuteReader()` when you're not writing a query? (Try `ExecuteNonQuery`.)

Comment: Yes i added in a block a code

Comment: Because the execute scalar does not work either

Comment: My bad, asking the question, I already modified the question

Comment: Try looking what query is being executed through `Profiler`, probably due to your `Where` clause, no lines are getting out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an output parameter at all. 
Use `ExecuteScalar` and it returns the value from your last statement SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Of course the command text should be changed in this way

```
string query   = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[ET_PERSONHASDEVICE] (
                  [ID_NATURALPERSON],[ID_DEVICE],[PD_MACADDRESS],
                  [PD_RECORDATE],[PD_STATUS],[CREATED_AT],[CREATED_BY])
                  SELECT ID_PERSON,1,@macAddress,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'A',
                         CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'ETC'
                  FROM [dbo].ET_PERSON WHERE PE_ADDRESS = @personAddress;
                  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
```

You could pass two statements to a single SqlCommand and receive the value of the last one executed, you need only to divide the two commands with a semicolon

Comment: doesn't work with the GetScalar, I already tried with that function and how it did not work for me, i change the execution by the ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: Perhaps is something different and linked to how do you build the command and the parameter's values. By the way, if doesn't insert any record then there is no IDENTITY to return.

Comment: make sense because it does not persists in the database, but the problem is just with the inserts because i had some query which returns an scalar and works well, Do you know what can be wrong with the connection

Comment: Your code above seems totally correct. Of course the @personAddress parameter matches one or more record in the source table right? Probably the code that builds the two parameters dictionaries and the code of GetSqlQueryCommand could help to understand what happens

Answer (score 2):

I am going to talk a bit about how to approach solving an issue like this.

First go to SSMS (or whatever interface you use to directly query a database for folks not using SQL Server) and run the select statment with the appropriate variable value. If it returns no records then you know why the insert is not working.

If it returns records then run the full insert. You may get an error that will tell you that you are missing a value for a required field or some other error. If there is no error then check the table to see if the data was inserted. If it was not, check for triggers on the table that could be rolling back the insert.

Once you know the statement works, then turn on profiler and try to run from the application using application code. Profiler will tell you what was sent, check it for differnces betweeen the SQL you have that works and what is sent. Often a variable won't get initialized and that is why there is no insert.

If you get no SQL from the Profiler, then look at the code in C# or whatever language you are writing in. At least now you know exactly where the problem has to lie.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `ExecuteReader()` does not "execute" its command until its result is enumerated. Instead, I would try with:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: already tried what happened in the code that i put in the question is that teesting I forgot the change it

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 command.Parameters["@ID_PERSONHASDEVICE"].Value=...
```

I have added `@` before `ID_PERSONHASDEVICE`, which I think was missing.